# Multiple table update design in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have learned more, and was compelled to find the solutions, mind changed.

PS dear experts, your help is appreciated in the time-saving nature of having forums and discussion in the first place, and also is mined for usefulness, not street cred. get helping or get off. The time I wasted reading posts where the answer was "I don't understand what you are trying to do..." and then questioning the OP with animus or incredulity, or suggesting some unrelated answer further confusing issues, is seemingly the problem with the world these days, if you want to help, help

**Original Post:**

Ok so as per the comments, thanks to ANYONE who volunteers any help with this problem.

I have a table and relationship design problem.

I have a table with a pk auto and I want to have a related table with a related column incrementally numbered that updates every time new data is entered in the form that is bound to it. It needs to update the related rows in the autonumbered table's key.

---the answer was to join the table on the autonumbered field.

The autonumber of the first table (main recordsource) is just an ID. I think I need two Primary Keys as I need to update the related record with that number in the entry form and move to NextRec but update the pk in the main table and move to NewRec , how do I join (see jpg image)?

I want enter results and update that existing record but update the adjoining pk so that a new record is created in the main table.

[Tourney](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZogm.jpg)

more in depth:

[From yours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH3vV.jpg)

[My desired form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alARQ.jpg)

note that the calculation table feeds the upcoming games table, where a query shows the players recent results. I would like to split the upcoming results to show the players' recent game history, the second tab I would like to enter either one result or many results at a time. I hope I am clearer. You can see why I have had a challenge. See my form though. The recordsource is the upcominggames table and the data entry form is for input (ENTER GAME DATA)

-----the answer to this was an update query (a separate form) and then requery the statistics form to show the new matchups that were entered.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I guess that the reason for the "downvotes" is that nobody can interprete your scribble. Please edit your post and and describe what you are trying to implement, what tables you are using, what data the users are intended to enter and what information you are trying to get out of that. (And yes, of course, "downvoting" without leaving a comment is quite unpolite, the users that did this should know that.)

Comment: I used a jpg image to display the characteristics is it not visible? I would only go in depth if what I want to make is feasible and if someone were willing to help. I'm sorry about the scribble part, which makes sense if you cant see the image. Thanks for helping me understand the downvotes. I am typing an edit to the post

Comment: Don't be upset with the people. For me, I can say that I did not have time yet to read you additional explanation after you added it. Just keep in mind that all here are volunteers, live in different corners of the planet, and for the experts: You can be sure of that no expert is unemployed. So: Be cool! ;-)

Comment: I was wrong to be insistent. I realize participation is optional, I stand corrected. In relation to the issue, I am still hung up and don't believe I can rely on any help. Except from you, thanks again. the updated explanation will go in the posts place, it's the same issue, I am just further along, I've been working at this design for months and have finally decided to reach out for help. Post continues above...

Comment: So you have two tables, *UpcomingGames* and *GameResults*, right? As the value `T_NUM` in *UpcomingGames* seems to be unique and manually entered, this should be the PK, no need for auto-numbering. If in the *GameResults* table it's also unique, it can be a FK and the PK at the same time, so there's a 1:1 relationship. In each relationship, the "left" side must exist before the right side (a game has to be planned before you can add a result to it). Maybe it's best to put all information in only one table *Games* (the planned game together with its result, which is entered at a later time)?

Comment: upcoming needs to be automatically filled incremented, there will never be any gaps or unused numbers, the resuIt is entered by a combo and then saved, I just can't seem to get it to work with the existing scheme

Comment: please see below, and vote up @Wolgang Kais's answer

Comment: Downvoted. Autonumbers  are created WHEN the database row becomes ditry, and they are NOT saved if you don't save the record. That means you can "many" times skip a given autonumber. If you open a form (or use VBA to add a database row), then Access will generate a autonumber and assign it to that row - but if you don't save the row, then that autonumber was never used, nor saved and will be skipped. Autonumber have VERY little to do with saving a record - they are issued when the row becomes dirty for the first time - but if you don't save the row, then that autonumber is never used (skipped)

Comment: great job, thanks. it's crazy that I would have to make a misstatement to get someone to explain it correctly. that info will help the first time for someone who comes across this.post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from the comments, this is what I'm thinking of when I read your description:

Since the *UpcomingGames* will be entered first and exactly one *GameResult* can be entered per *UpcomingGame*, this will be a 1:1 relationship. As the name *Upcoming* says: The *Upcoming* data has to be entered before the *Result* can make sense. Unless an *UpcomingGame* can be cancelled, there will indeed be a *Result* for the *Game*, so there is no need to separate the information into 2 tables. I'd say, a user interface could look like this:

[image]

As you can see, the `T_NUM` column is an autovalue. Before entering any data, I initialized that column using a query like this (and deleted that record afterwards):

```
INSERT INTO Games ( T_NUM )
VALUES (1004);
```

This way, the numbering started with number 1005.

You won't be able to to avoid gaps in the numbering, as long as the users can remove existing records or cancel the insertion of a new record. If you want at least to avoid the latter, you will need some VBA code in the form.

Comment: Yes, good looking Wolfy!  but there is only one next t_NUM, and only one user at a time (me :) ). But there is a need for 2 tables one for the data entry and the join table for the third table in the bunch (the calculations are a combination of values (see image jpg). I don't want to enter the the two teams, if possible, just leave an open slot for the entries to be made, the new t_NUM should be open and awaiting input when I open the form. Note the form recordsource is =DMAX("[T_NUM]","RESULTS")

Comment: Do I need this in the table?  SELECT MAX([ID]) + 1 FROM [TableName]; or something like it?

Comment: by the way I like this answer for summing up the wins losses to be shown as an avg or something, an answer you provided elsewhere                                                                         INSERT INTO tblCALCS (NUMOFGAMES, NumWin, NumLoss )
SELECT ? AS Expr1, ? AS Expr2, Sum(IIf([Members].[Active]=Yes,1,0)) AS Expr3
FROM Members;

Comment: @CJtheLion The data can be separated in 2 tables, where `T_NUM` also would be the PK of the `GameResults` table, but not as an AutoNumber but just Number (Long Integer). The form could still be the same, it should be based on a query like this:
`SELECT UpcomingGames.T_NUM, UpcomingGames.Home, UpcomingGames.Guest, GaneResults.Won, GaneResults.Lost FROM UpcomingGames LEFT JOIN GaneResults ON UpcomingGames.T_NUM = GaneResults.T_NUM;`. This way, only those T_NUMs appear in the *GameResults* table, that have data entered.

Comment: You might need the DMAX formula if you didn't want to use an AutoNumber field.

Comment: I'm marking this answered. I would still like help, but I thank you for your time. For the record, Some people are just learning, and sometimes concepts can elude them, with no way to ask questions and get answers. Not everyone has the budget for college classes or the time to read every post, view every video, or review every website that purports to helpful. @Wolfgang Kais is the kind of person the world needs more of, helpful and patient. Unfortunately, I am stuck still, but I see a few new concepts. For example, a Query solves the update problem, with an after update and a table data macro

Comment: @CJtheLion Thanks a lot, Be patient with yourself. Me too didn't learn MS Access within a week, it took me 23 years to arrive where I am today. :-)